# Annotation_logticks() Error. Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 8L, 7L, 6L, : replacement has 41 rows, data has 1

Tags: r, ggplot2, logging, scale, geom-bar

I am trying to add log ticks to the y axis of the bar plot below.

[Bar Plot I am trying to add log ticks to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh8z7.png)

The plot works fine with the following code, without logticks:

```
    plot <- ggplot(data_long, aes(fill= data_long$variable, y= data_long$value, x= data_long$variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", ) 

plot <- plot + scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Casirivimab" = "brown2", "Imdevimab" = "darkorchid1", "Bamlanivimab" = "mediumblue","Etesevimab" = "deeppink", "Sotrovimab" = "cyan3", "Regdanvimab" = "yellow2", "Etesevimab + Bamlanivimab" = "magenta3", "Casirivimab + Imdevimab" = "chartreuse4" ))

plot <- plot + theme(aspect.ratio=1/2, axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) 
plot <- plot + scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) 
plot <- plot + annotation_logticks()

plot <- plot + facet_wrap(factor(data_long$Variant, levels = c("B.1.351", "P.1", "B.1.617", "B.1.617.1", "B.1.617.2", "B.1.1.7", "B.1.427", "B.1.429", "B.1.525")), ncol = 9) + labs (x = "", y = "Fold Change Neutralisation", fill = "mAb") 

plot <- plot + theme(aspect.ratio=6/2,)

plot <- plot + theme(legend.key.size = unit(0.2, 'cm') )

plot <- plot + theme(panel.grid = element_blank())

plot <- plot + geom_text(aes(label = N), nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = 0.25, color="black",vjust = 0.5,hjust = 1.2)

plot
```

However adding the annotation_logticks() function creates an error.

```
    plot <- plot + annotation_lockticks()  
    plot
```

The error is

> Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 8L, 7L, 6L,
> :    replacement has 41 rows, data has 1

EDIT: here is the data via dput() :

```
    structure(list(Variant = c("B.1.351", "B.1.429", "B.1.427", "B.1.1.7", 
"B.1.617.2", "B.1.617.1", "B.1.617", "P.1", "B.1.351", "B.1.429", 
"B.1.427", "B.1.1.7", "B.1.617.2", "B.1.617.1", "B.1.617", "P.1", 
"B.1.351", "B.1.429", "B.1.1.7", "B.1.617.2", "B.1.617.1", "B.1.617", 
"P.1", "B.1.351", "B.1.429", "B.1.427", "B.1.1.7", "B.1.617.2", 
"B.1.617.1", "B.1.617", "P.1", "B.1.351", "P.1", "B.1.617.2", 
"B.1.351", "B.1.617", "B.1.351", "B.1.429", "B.1.1.7", "B.1.617.1", 
"B.1.617"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L), .Label = c("Casirivimab", "Imdevimab", "Bamlanivimab", 
"Etesevimab", "Sotrovimab", "Regdanvimab", "Etesevimab...Bamlanivimab", 
"Casirivimab...Imdevimab"), class = "factor"), value = c(862.1, 
0.9, 1, 1.4, 1, 17.6, 3.6, 69.6, 1, 5, 0.7, 1.1, 4.2, 3.8, 1, 
0.6, 169209.3, 2000, 1.7, 4175.6, 1700, 450, 1814.5, 11140.6, 
0.9, 2.1, 5.5, 0.5, 1.2, 0.9, 11915, 0.5, 0.7, 13, 300, 4.7, 
1.3, 0.8, 0.6, 0.8, 1), N = c(8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
8L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L)), row.names = c(NA, -41L), class = "data.frame")
```

any ideas on how to get around this?
Thanks

Comment: can you share your data using `dput()`?

Comment: Hi @neuron - I have included the data via dput() as an edit. Hopefully this helps? Thanks for taking the time on this

Comment: I believe my answer should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the code you provided in your question. The easiest way to order the plots AND add the log scale on the side of the graph, you need to factor the `Variant` column in your dataframe. You can then apply `facet_grid` to the factored column and the log tick scale.

```
data_long$Variant_f <- factor(data_long$Variant, levels=c("B.1.351", "P.1", "B.1.617", "B.1.617.1", "B.1.617.2", "B.1.1.7", "B.1.427", "B.1.429", "B.1.525"))

plot <- ggplot(data_long, aes(fill= data_long$variable, y= data_long$value, x= data_long$variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Casirivimab" = "brown2", "Imdevimab" = "darkorchid1", "Bamlanivimab" = "mediumblue","Etesevimab" = "deeppink", "Sotrovimab" = "cyan3", "Regdanvimab" = "yellow2", "Etesevimab + Bamlanivimab" = "magenta3", "Casirivimab + Imdevimab" = "chartreuse4")) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1/2, axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  annotation_logticks(sides = "l") +
  facet_grid(col = vars(Variant_f)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = N), nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = 0.25, color="black",vjust = 0.5,hjust = 1.2) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=6/2,
        legend.key.size = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

There are some aesthetics that need to be fixed in the graph but it achieves your goal.

[image: example1]

If you want to only apply the log tick scale to ONE of the graphs you can use a function. NOTE that this is optional. However, I think it looks better.

Function to add the ticks to one graph:

```
add_logticks  <- function (base = 10, sides = "bl", scaled = TRUE, 
                           short = unit(0.1, "cm"), mid = unit(0.2, "cm"),  long = unit(0.3, "cm"), 
                           colour = "black",  size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = 1, color = NULL, 
                           data =data.frame(x = NA),... )   {
  if (!is.null(color)) 
    colour <- color
  layer(geom = "logticks", params = list(base = base, 
                                              sides = sides, scaled = scaled, short = short, 
                                              mid = mid, long = long, colour = colour, size = size, 
                                              linetype = linetype, alpha = alpha, ...), 
        stat = "identity", data = data , mapping = NULL, inherit.aes = FALSE, position = "identity",
        show.legend = FALSE)
}
```

Then the plot:

```
plot <- ggplot(data_long, aes(fill= data_long$variable, y= data_long$value, x= data_long$variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual("legend", values = c("Casirivimab" = "brown2", "Imdevimab" = "darkorchid1", "Bamlanivimab" = "mediumblue","Etesevimab" = "deeppink", "Sotrovimab" = "cyan3", "Regdanvimab" = "yellow2", "Etesevimab + Bamlanivimab" = "magenta3", "Casirivimab + Imdevimab" = "chartreuse4")) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=1/2, axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) + 
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                                  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  #annotation_logticks(sides = "l") +
  facet_grid(col = vars(Variant_f)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = N), nudge_x = 0.5, nudge_y = 0.25, color="black",vjust = 0.5,hjust = 1.2) +
  theme(aspect.ratio=6/2,
        legend.key.size = unit(0.2, 'cm'),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Then apply to the plot:

```
plot + add_logticks(side = 'l', data = data.frame(x= NA, Variant_f = 'B.1.351'))
```

[image: example2]

Comment: that's great thank you. *There is a small issue however*. Your method reorders the grid facets (B.1.1.7 comes first in yours, but B.1.351 is first in mine). This is important. I was able to get around this when using the first part of you method by re-ordering the variants in the original data set. This gave a plot with the facets in the correct order, logticks on all of the facets. Using logticks function successfully put ticks on only one of the plots/ facets, but it again jumbles up the order then appear in. Any ideas?

Comment: @M.J.Cox I updated my answer based on your comment above